# If double digit precision is ≈15.955 (16), why can I print 50 digits?

Tags: c++, double

Of course [that's](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/20f3dbaaf60d573e) not magic:

```
double in = 1.0 / 7.0;

cout.precision(50);
cout << in << endl;
```

but why can I see `0.14285714285714284921269268124888185411691665649414` (i.e. 51 digits)?

Double precision has 53 bits for precision (thus should be 15.955=16 slots).

`cout` invent numbers? :P

Comment: Well only the first 16 digits are correct

Comment: The algorithm that takes the parameter passed to `precision()` doesn't work based on theory. It'll loop that many times and produce that result, I imagine, regardless of how many bits of real information is in the floating point number...

Comment: If my value is `1.0`, I can write as many 0s as I want, it won't mean that I increased the initial precision. It's just that adding binary 0s doesn't translate to 0s in decimal.

Comment: As an intuitive (?) explanation: with two bits of floating-point precision, you can represent for instance 0.75 exactly - two decimals. With three, 0.125 - three decimals. With four bits, 0.56125 - five decimals. And so on...

Answer (score 4):

Precision is related to two similar notions:

- The difference between the actual value and the target value (i.e. the mathematical result of 1/7).
- The minimum difference between neighbouring values.

In both cases, that 15.9x relates to how many of those decimal digits are useful/meaningful in differentiating values.

That says nothing about the number of decimal places required to accurately represent those values.  As [@dasblinkenlight says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39124825/129570), that number is potentially large in the case of double-precision floats.

Answer (score 3):

This is because `double`s are composed of "building blocks" that translate to multiple digits when converted to decimal.

A `double` has binary representation as a combination of positive and negative powers of two. With 11-bit exponent, a `double` is capable of representing numbers as small as 2<sup>-1024</sup>.

When you convert a negative power of two to decimal representation, the number of decimal digits is equal to the absolute value of the power (see [this table](http://www.exploringbinary.com/a-table-of-negative-powers-of-two/) for a list of negative powers of two up to -64). All these decimal digits are perfectly valid, so a double can represent a number that has a thousand digits when converted to decimal.

Comment: To see this from other side, take the value `0.3`. It's single significant digit in decimal format ("3") representing the value completely and exactly, yet the binary encoding will yield infinite `0.01001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011...`, so taking only 53bits of that is just an approximation of `0.3`, not the exact original value. The error is smaller than the 1e-16 (that's the "16 digits precision"). From binary to decimal you can always calculate the *exact* decimal representation as 1/2^n values have always some exact finite decimal form.

Comment: ~750 digits for a 64 bit `double`, if my estimates are correct.

Answer (score 0):

What you see is the result of the conversion from the internal *binary* representation of the number 1/7 (which is as close to that number as a `double` can be) to a decimal representation of it.

Now, 1/7 can't be represented by a finite sequence of bits in base 2, but any value stored in a `double` can be transformed in base 10 with a finite number of digits, just more then 50.

Consider this snippet, where I set the precision of the output to 100:

```
cout.precision(100);
for ( int i = 2; i <= 10; ++i) {
    cout << "1 / " << i << " = " << 1.0 / i << endl;
}
```

You can see in the result how many figures are need:

```
1 / 2 = 0.5
1 / 3 = 0.333333333333333314829616256247390992939472198486328125
1 / 4 = 0.25
1 / 5 = 0.200000000000000011102230246251565404236316680908203125
1 / 6 = 0.1666666666666666574148081281236954964697360992431640625
1 / 7 = 0.142857142857142849212692681248881854116916656494140625
1 / 8 = 0.125
1 / 9 = 0.111111111111111104943205418749130330979824066162109375
1 / 10 = 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625
```

Answer (score -5):

53 binary digits only equals 15.9xx decimal digits before the decimal point. After the decimal point it is another story.

Comment: Lol at the downvotes. EJP you could maybe please tell us the story of "After the decimal point"? I will go get my popcorn.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Just consider 1 and 0.1. The first takes one bit. The second takes more than 53. Because it's a fraction.

Comment: Not because it's a fraction.  The same is true for non-fractional numbers: 1024 takes one bit, 1023 takes 9.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth And how many bits does 0.1024 take? and why?

Comment: @EJP - Several, I imagine?  But again, that's not because it's a fraction, it's because it's not a neat multiple of a power of two.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth What do you mean with 1024 takes one bit? Just because only one bit is 1 it doesn't mean it takes only bit. The less significant bits are very important.

Comment: @exilit: as in, a floating point representation with a 1-bit mantissa (actually, zero-bit on practice) would be able to exactly represent it.